# How to make font the same style like others?

Tags: css, responsive-design, navigation

I started to work on little project and have a hard time to set submenus without categories inside to have the same style. See image bellow:

[image]

i tryed to modify CSS class:

```
span.menu-style
```

but seems that not effect done. The problem is when some category is empty, when have one elements inside all is ok. How to make all titles to have the same style (bold and uppercase) not depending if have some cateogory or not?

To see the issue on live site, please click [here](https://www.makesensestore.com/product-category/apple-accessories/)

then navigate in : ALL DEPARTMENTS > Apple Accessories and scroll down to afftected category. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why can't you just target the class `.menu-title`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is, how to make all titles the same style?

I tryed this:

`.menu-title {
font-style: inherit;
}`

but dont see any changes. Note that only empty category have that issue, like that in image under. Other categories that have subcategory is OK. I want to make all the same, not depending if have subcategory or not.

Comment: Why not add the styles to `.menu-title`?

Comment: OK but i dont know the style of other titles.. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edited*

```
.dropdown-menu > li:not(.dropdown-submenu) .menu-title { 
  font-size: 16px; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-weight: 700; 
}
```

Comment: That makes all text (including subcategories) with uppercase. I need only empty categories like showed in image.

Comment: @Dora - I missed that. Edited answer, let me know if helps

Comment: The same.. All text is Uppercased. :(

Dropdown menus dont need to be uppercased !

Comment: The same.. All text is uppercased.

Comment: Seems not uppercased, but see the style on that category without subcategories inside.

http://i.imgur.com/b4dU7jf.png?1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141375/discussion-between-ovokuro-and-dora).

Answer (score 1):

There's two things you can do. You can target all anchors `a` that are a child of an list element `li` that **don't** have the class `.dropdown-submenu` or you can target specific menu items via the classes that are added to the anchors `a` parent list item `li`.

#### First option, target all anchors.

The WordPress theme you're using is adding a `.dropdown-submenu` class to all list items `li` that have a submenu and omits it if it doesn't. *iPod & TV Accessories* doesn't have any menu items so it doesn't get this class. So we need to target those anchors and add the same styles that targets the anchors `a` that have a parent list item `li` with the class `.dropdown-submenu`. We do this with CSS pesudo class [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). But first, here's the CSS selector generating the styles we need to copy:

```
.wrapper_vertical_menu .vertical-megamenu > li.revo-mega-menu > .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-submenu > a {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Now copy all the properties and modify the property to the following:

```
.dropdown-menu > li:not( .dropdown-submenu ) > a {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Make sure to apply this override somewhere other than the themes CSS file as it could get overwritten in the future on an update and you'll have to redo it.

#### Second option, target specific menu items via custom classes.

The menu item *iPod & TV Accessories* has the class `.menu-ipod-tv-accessories` applied to it's list item `li`.

```
.dropdown-menu > li.menu-ipod-tv-accessories > a {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Then if you had more it might look like this:

```
.dropdown-menu > li.menu-ipod-tv-accessories > a,
.dropdown-menu > li.menu-universal-accessories > a,
.dropdown-menu > li.menu-apple-watch-accessories > a {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The style for the titles:

```
.menu-title{
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #222;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: 'LoraItalic'; 
}
```

Comment: This makes all text (titles and subcategories) to be uppercased. I want only titles to be the same style.

See image what cause this CSS: http://i.imgur.com/pXswXHf.png?1

Comment: Try to use this css class (main-title) on 'a tag' not on span

Comment: for example? Can you send example?

Answer (score -1):

To apply the same style to multiple and different classes/elements, you can add the needed selectors to your css file, i.e.

`li a, .class_of_your_choice, #id_of_your_choice, ... {
/* css style that needs to be applied to every selector above */
}`

Comment: The issue is that i dont know the CSS styling on other category that have subcategories inside. Looks that have one style for categories that have subcategories, and others that is empty like "Ipod & TV Accessiories"